# todo list MVC model in java script

Tags: javascript

I'm making a todo list app in javascript by MVC model. Now I have the problem with `check-all` button. The requirement is when user click `check-all` buttoon, all items is checked and system will count the elements active. But now it not count right.

[picture show right case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VZie.png)

You can follow my code at http://codepen.io/dienvm/pen/RpXZKE?editors=1010

thanks for your support after!

Comment: can u describe ur issue a bit more detailed pls? I just created 3 todos, checked all and counted was 3... after "clear completed" the counter is still the old one -> is this ur issue?

Comment: created 3 todos -> check Mark all as complete (check-all) button -> the count return to 0 item left (it right case), but now it still return current items

Comment: I just update the picture to description right case I want to do, pls follow it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function get active todos is in fact returning all todos that have not been marked as completed. However toggleAll is not setting all of the todos to completed. The following should work fine.

```
store.isMarkAll = true

function toggleAll () {
    var toggleAll = document.getElementById('toggle-all')

    toggleAll.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      var list = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle')

      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         list[i].checked = this.checked
       }
      store.todos = store.todos.map(function(todo) {
        todo.completed = store.isMarkAll;
        return todo;
      })
      store.isMarkAll = !store.isMarkAll
      store.todos.completed = this.checked
      renderCount()
    })
 }
```

Comment: It work fire, thanks for your support

And I still have problem with filter item by `all`, `active` and `completed`. By default it show all items. When click `active` buttton it only show item unchecked item, and when cleck `completed` button it only show checked item. Can you help me do it.

Comment: can you help me

Comment: Ok, I am not quit sure of what you want help with though.

Do you want the active and complete links to be able to correctly filter?

Comment: you can see at the footer I have 3 li `all`, `active` and `completed`. When user click `all` tag it show every items todo. If user just click `active` tag it only show items that `checked box === false`. If user click `completed` taf it only show items that `checked box === true`.
It clearly for you

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the `todo` from your `todo list`, that you call as `this.todos = []`.

You are deleting it from the DOM, but your array still the same.